# Ensure that one lifetime outlives another in tree

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm having a hard time figuring out the lifetime syntax that I need for the following code, which does not compile. The basic idea is that I'm creating an Abstract Syntax Tree, and each node must have a different type. Some node types must hold a reference to an external value. It's not possible to make this external value an owned type; it's actually a reference to disk file that must be shared by a number of nodes. Here's the code, as simple as I can make it:

```
trait Node {
    fn init(&mut self, my_str: &str);
}

struct NodeParent {
    pub children: Vec<Box<dyn Node>>,
}

impl Node for NodeParent {
    fn init(&mut self, my_str: &str) {
        for child in self.children.iter_mut() {
            child.init(my_str);
        }
    }
}

struct NodeLeaf<'a> {
    pub my_str: Option<&'a str>,
}

impl Node for NodeLeaf<'_> {
    fn init(&mut self, my_str: &str) {
        self.my_str = Some(my_str);
    }
}

impl NodeLeaf<'_> {
    pub fn new() -> Box<dyn Node> {
        Box::new(NodeLeaf { my_str: None })
    }
}

pub fn make_ast() {
    let mut parent = NodeParent { children: vec![] };
    let leaf = NodeLeaf::new();
    parent.children.push(leaf);

    let some_string = String::from("foo");
    let my_str = some_string.as_str();
    parent.init(my_str);
}
```

The error is:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/query/lifetime_test.rs:23:9
   |
22 |     fn init(&mut self, my_str: &str) {
   |             ---------          - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |             |
   |             has type `&mut NodeLeaf<'2>`
23 |         self.my_str = Some(my_str);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ assignment requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

I know I need some kind of lifetime on `&my_str` everywhere it appears, but once I start taking the compiler's suggestion to start adding lifetimes here and there they proliferate, and I never get to code that compiles. I've also tried to `Rc<>`, but the code to make that work eludes me as well.

How do I specify that `&my_str` outlives the whole Node tree?

[Link to the code on Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b104a3b896ac5801090373ff3ed90c62)

Comment: For AST it is often better to use enums.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, I tried that, but how can I have a different init() method for each variant? The issue is performance: I actually have a next() method which is different for each node type, and I can't add a match(nodetype) call within the method because it needs to get called literally millions of times per second.

Comment: `match` can, and likely will, be faster than dynamic dispatch of traits. Bench it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I rewrote my code so the nodes are now enums. Haven't benchmarked it yet, but the code is way cleaner now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a lifetime to `Node`:

```rust
trait Node<'a> {
    fn init(&mut self, my_str: &'a str);
}

struct NodeParent<'a> {
    pub children: Vec<Box<dyn Node<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> for NodeParent<'a> {
    fn init(&mut self, my_str: &'a str) {
        for child in self.children.iter_mut() {
            child.init(my_str);
        }
    }
}

struct NodeLeaf<'a> {
    pub my_str: Option<&'a str>,
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> for NodeLeaf<'a> {
    fn init(&mut self, my_str: &'a str) {
        self.my_str = Some(my_str);
    }
}

impl<'a> NodeLeaf<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Box<dyn Node<'a>> {
        Box::new(NodeLeaf { my_str: None })
    }
}
```

But this is not enough, because `Box<dyn Node<'a>>` is actually `Box<dyn Node<'a> + 'static>`, that is, it cannot contain any non-`'static` lifetime. You need to specify that it can contain lifetime `'a`:

```rust
struct NodeParent<'a> {
    pub children: Vec<Box<dyn Node<'a> + 'a>>,
}

impl<'a> NodeLeaf<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Box<dyn Node<'a> + 'a> {
        Box::new(NodeLeaf { my_str: None })
    }
}
```

Now you will get a different error:

```
error[E0597]: `some_string` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:39:18
   |
39 |     let my_str = some_string.as_str();
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
40 |     parent.init(my_str);
41 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `some_string` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `parent` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `NodeParent<'_>`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

Because `Box<dyn Node>` may have an arbitrary destructor, and it may access the stored string, we need to make sure it is still alive when the value is dropped. Do that by moving the string creation before the nodes:

```rust
pub fn make_ast() {
    let some_string = String::from("foo");
    let mut parent = NodeParent { children: vec![] };
    let leaf = NodeLeaf::new();
    parent.children.push(leaf);

    let my_str = some_string.as_str();
    parent.init(my_str);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9e682b0097b7290a73cd01e49da92104).